# Table of contents with previous sections

Tags: table-of-contents

I explain better what I meant in the title.

I have the table of contents showing as normal all chapters and sections that come after the table of contents itself..

Before it I have the abstract and the acknowledgements

How can I include them in the table of contents?

What I have is

```
\usepackage[hyperindex]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\include{Acknowledgements}
\clearemptydoublepage
\include{Abstract}
\clearemptydoublepage

\lhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thepage}]%
  {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries Table of contents}}
\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\bfseries Table of contents}]%
  {\fancyplain{}{\bfseries \thepage}}
\cfoot{}%
\tableofcontents
\clearemptydoublepage
```

Thanks

Comment: Please complete to a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228). The document class is important. Also use a sketch (minimal version) for the abstract and the acknowledgements sections. We do not have the files `Acknowledgements.tex` and `Abstact.tex`.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your document class is 'book':

```
\documentclass[openany]{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}   % get some filler text
\usepackage{emptypage}% strip headers and numbers from otherwise empty pages

\begin{document}

\frontmatter          % switch off chapter numbering, use roman page nums

\chapter{Abstract} 

\lipsum[1]

\chapter{Acknowledgements}

\lipsum[2]


\tableofcontents

\mainmatter  % switch on chapter numbering, use arabic page numbers

\chapter{Another day in paradise}

\lipsum[3]

\backmatter   % for index, bibliography, appendix

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, I was using chapter* to avoid numbering in acknowledgements and abstract, I didn't know the \frontmatter command

Comment: Yes, `\frontmatter` doesn't get the attention it deserves. I have struggled with this in the past as well.